# C# UWP How to enable Cortana Checking conditions and responds back to you

Tags: c#, uwp, cortana

Hey guys I have a simple UWP app that I have integrated with Cortana. So I am looking for a post or a sample codes where when am going to tell cortana, "Hey Cortana check the available jobs" then before it checks it says "which one a or b " then I say a.

When I says a, it reads the title of that job Note: Not the one I have provided on the feedback XML file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and test the official [CortanaVoiceCommand](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) sample, if you can define the voice command and the corresponding response correctly, you can achieve it.

There is a similar scenario in the official sample, when we say "cancel trip to london", the cortana will filter the trip of going to london, then give you a response to ask you whether you want to cancel it, then you can say "yes" or "No" to confirm.

For the code, you can see the `voiceCommandService` background task, it has different behavior to handle the different command.

Moreover, you can also look into the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/interact-with-a-background-app-in-cortana#span-idhand-offscreenspanspan-idhand-offscreenspanspan-idhand-offscreenspanhand-off-screen